# Google Sheets Intermittent IMPORTRANGE not working and app script is unable to read the data from cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My biggest issue is occasionally my google sheets app script cannot read the contents of cells. It will stop working for 5-30 minutes, then start working again. This is a live scoring sheet so that is a big problem not being able to save data for for pretty large chunks of time.

I have tried getting the cell data in multiple ways:
ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('L1').getValue()
I also created an array by using getValues() for a range and using the data from that array.
Both ways work for a while, it will go hours without an issue then just not be able to read the cell contents.

```
function SaveScore(btn) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // ss is now the spreadsheet the script is associated with
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1rKzGRC7gAWKc1m4yrEDYlospgE-JcAxngV-70rNTbTs').getSheetByName('Announcer');

  var scoreData = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('A1:Q7').getValues();
  //var curDrawRow = ss.getSheetByName('Setup').getRange('I11').getValue();
  var curDrawRow = scoreData[4][16];


  //var scoreJ1 = scoreData[1][1];
  //var scoreJ2 = scoreData[1][2];
  //var scoreJ3 = scoreData[1][3];
  //var scoreTotal = scoreData[1][4];
  //var classNum = scoreData[0][11];

  //var drawNumb = scoreData[3][0];
  //var exhNum = scoreData[3][8];

  var curOffset = scoreData[6][16];
  //var curOffset = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('Q7').getValue();
  //var scoreJ1 = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('B2').getValue();
  var scoreJ1 = scoreData[1][1];
  //var scoreJ2 = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('C2').getValue();
  var scoreJ2 = scoreData[1][2];
  //var scoreJ3 = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('D2').getValue();
  var scoreJ3 = scoreData[1][3];
  //var scoreTotal = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('E2').getValue();
  var scoreTotal = scoreData[1][4];
  //var classNum = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('L1').getValue();
  var classNum = scoreData[0][11];
  //var drawNumb = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('Raw Data!A' + (curDrawRow + curOffset)).getValue();
  var drawNumb = scoreData[3][0];
  //if (drawNumb == '') {
  //  var drawNumb = ss.getSheetByName('Raw Data').getRange('A' + (curDrawRow + curOffset)).getValue();
  //}
  //if (drawNumb == '') {
  //  var drawNumb = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('A4').getValue();
  //}
  //var exhNum = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('Raw Data!B' + (curDrawRow + curOffset)).getValue();
  var exhNum = scoreData[3][8];

  //if (exhNum == '') {
  //  var exhNum = ss.getSheetByName('Raw Data').getRange('B' + (curDrawRow + curOffset)).getValue();
  //}
  //if (exhNum == '') {
  //  var drawNumb = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('I4').getValue();
  //}

  if (scoreTotal == '--' && btn != 'review') {
    ui.alert('Please enter a score');
    ss.getActiveSheet().setActiveRange(ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2'));
  }else if (classNum == '') {
    ui.alert('Class # is blank. This is a google syncing issue and typically will fix itself in about 5-10 minutes. Please wait and try again in 5-10 minutes.');
  }else if (drawNumb == '') {
    ui.alert('Draw # is blank. This is a google syncing issue and typically will fix itself in about 5-10 minutes. Please wait and try again in 5-10 minutes.');
  }else if (exhNum == '') {
    ui.alert('Exhibitor # is blank. This is a google syncing issue and typically will fix itself in about 5-10 minutes. Please wait and try again in 5-10 minutes.');
  }else{
}
```

// if I get this far the rest of the code will work. I often get the alert for Draw # is blank, or Exhibitor # is blank.

I expect drawNumb and exhNum to be numbers every time. But when it's not working, they are both blank.

Comment: Is there some quota that I'm hitting?

Comment: Try to replace ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('A1:Q7').getValues(); by ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getDataRange.getValues();

Comment: *Also ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('Raw Data!A' + (curDrawRow + curOffset)).getValue(); is not valid the Raw Data is a sheet name so it must be ss.getSheetByName('Raw Data').getRange('A' + (curDrawRow + curOffset)).getValue() the function getValue() consume lot of time to be treated so that is true it is better to use a big table using getDataRange than multiplying the getValue()

Comment: Could you please share a copy of the Sheets? Removing any private/personal information of course.

Comment: Remove this `else{` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function runOne(btn) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // ss is now the spreadsheet the script is associated with
  var scoreData = ss.getSheetByName('Announcer').getRange('A1:Q7').getValues();
  var curDrawRow = scoreData[4][16];
  var curOffset = scoreData[6][16];
  var scoreJ1 = scoreData[1][1];
  var scoreJ2 = scoreData[1][2];
  var scoreJ3 = scoreData[1][3];
  var scoreTotal = scoreData[1][4];
  var classNum = scoreData[0][11];
  var drawNumb = scoreData[3][0];
  var exhNum = scoreData[3][8];
  if (scoreTotal == '--' && btn != 'review') {
    ui.alert('Please enter a score');
    ss.getActiveSheet().setActiveRange(ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2'));
  }else if (classNum == '') {
    ui.alert('Class # is blank. This is a google syncing issue and typically will fix itself in about 5-10 minutes. Please wait and try again in 5-10 minutes.');
  }else if (drawNumb == '') {
    ui.alert('Draw # is blank. This is a google syncing issue and typically will fix itself in about 5-10 minutes. Please wait and try again in 5-10 minutes.');
  }else if (exhNum == '') {
    ui.alert('Exhibitor # is blank. This is a google syncing issue and typically will fix itself in about 5-10 minutes. Please wait and try again in 5-10 minutes.');
  }
}
```